# angular 2 (2.0.0-rc1) how to create a child injector on code

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I need to call the following code with a new injector created to add providers dynamically:

```
var componentRef = componentFactory.create(
    injector, undefined, `#${this.id}`
);
```

I can't find an example on the internet on howto create a child injector whose parent is the component injector. Any ideas?

I have tried to inject a `ReflectiveInjector` (so i can call `resolveAndCreateChild` method) into may component but an exception is raised at runtime saying there is no provider for that class.

Answer (score 1):

inject Injector and then

```
        let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([new Provider('node', { useValue: node })]);
        let child = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this.injector);
```